# Get min/max values from fields in array

Tags: java

So I have a class called station and it holds a list of readings that holds temperature, windSpeed and pressure.

What would be the nicest way of getting min/max values of temperature, windSpeed and pressure?

This is how I have done it. But I don't know it feels wrong.

```
public static void setMinMaxValues(Station station) {
  station.temperatureMin = station.windSpeedMin = station.pressureMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
  for (Reading reading : station.readings) {
    if (station.temperatureMin > reading.temperature) station.temperatureMin = reading.temperature;
    if (station.temperatureMax < reading.temperature) station.temperatureMax = reading.temperature;
    if (station.windSpeedMin > reading.windSpeed) station.windSpeedMin = reading.windSpeed;
    if (station.windSpeedMax < reading.windSpeed) station.windSpeedMax = reading.windSpeed;
    if (station.pressureMin > reading.pressure) station.pressureMin = reading.pressure;
    if (station.pressureMax < reading.pressure) station.pressureMax = reading.pressure;
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions of how to improve it, or what could I look into to make it better.

Comment: `improve it or make it better`: Why? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [streaming](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to compute the them without an explicit loop.

```
public static void setMinMaxValues(Station station) {
  station.temperatureMin = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.temperature).min().orElse(Double.NaN);
  station.temperatureMax = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.temperature).max().orElse(Double.NaN);
  station.windSpeedMin = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.windSpeed).min().orElse(Double.NaN);
  station.windSpeedMax = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.windSpeed).max().orElse(Double.NaN);
  station.pressureMin = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.pressure).min().orElse(Double.NaN);
  station.pressureMax = station.readings.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.pressure).max().orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```

Computing the values in one shot more clearly expresses intention, IMO. It also gives you better
control over how to handle a lack of readings: you could use `NaN` as shown above, or you could
leave them as `OptionalDouble`s, or you could decline to update the old values.

It does, however, require six passes over the readings, which is a bummer. You could reduce it to three by using [`summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) to compute the min and maxes of each value simultaneously.

```
public static void setMinMaxValues(Station station) {
  DoubleSummaryStatistics temperatureStats = station.readings.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(s -> s.temperature));
  DoubleSummaryStatistics windSpeedStats = station.readings.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(s -> s.windSpeed));
  DoubleSummaryStatistics pressureStats = station.readings.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(s -> s.pressure));

  station.temperatureMin = temperatureStats.getMin();
  station.temperatureMax = temperatureStats.getMax();
  station.windSpeedMin = windSpeedStats.getMin();
  station.windSpeedMax = windSpeedStats.getMax();
  station.pressureMin = pressureStats.getMin();
  station.pressureMax = pressureStats.getMax();
}
```

If there are no readings this will assign +∞ to the mins and -∞ to the maxes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) Class. You can e. g. replace

```java
if (station.temperatureMin > reading.temperature) station.temperatureMin = reading.temperature;
```

with

```java
station.temperatureMin = Math.min(station.temperatureMin, reading.temperature);
```

There of course is a `Math.max()` as well